# How to install these packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, node-sass

I'm having trouble starting up the frontend of a project. When I run `npm install` I get a ton of C warnings from node-sass, then a few errors and then the installation fails. I've tried looking through the error logs and I'm stuck.

Using npm version 6.14.4 and node version 16.15.0 on Ubuntu.

package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "./",
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.16.11",
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "deve": "0.0.0",
    "manifest": "^0.1.4",
    "manifest-rev": "^1.0.3",
    "mobx": "^5.14.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-resize-detector": "^4.2.1",
    "react-rnd": "^9.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-scripts-ts": "^4.0.8",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "git-info": "echo export default {logMessage: \\\"$(git log -1 --oneline)\\\"}\\;  > src/static/gitInfo.ts",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/main.*",
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar -q src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar -q src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "start": "npm run git-info; npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts-ts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
    "build": "npm run git-info; npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.24",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-resize-detector": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "chokidar-cli": "^2.1.0",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^6.1.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.5",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "browserslist": []
}
```

error after running `npm install` (some output omitted)

```
/home/ttamre/.node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
  492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      remove_cv
/home/ttamre/.node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
  492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      remove_cv
/home/ttamre/.node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
      |                                                  ^
/home/ttamre/.node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:63: error: ‘::Perform’ has not been declared
  492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
      |                                                               ^~~~~~~
../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/binding.cpp:284:80: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
  284 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
      |                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render_file(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/binding.cpp:320:80: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
  320 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
      |                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:58,
                 from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
../src/binding.cpp: At global scope:
/home/ttamre/.node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/node.h:847:7: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
  847 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ttamre/.node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/node.h:881:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
  881 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/binding.cpp:358:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
  358 | NODE_MODULE(binding, RegisterModule);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [binding.target.mk:133: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/ttamre/Documents/CIRADA/website/gui/web/frontend/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ttamre/Documents/CIRADA/website/gui/web/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-27-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/ttamre/Documents/CIRADA/website/gui/web/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ttamre/Documents/CIRADA/website/gui/web/frontend/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/react-scripts-ts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/react-scripts-ts/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/jest-circus/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/@jest/transform/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/@jest/test-sequencer/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/@jest/reporters/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ttamre/.npm/_logs/2022-05-04T21_49_20_323Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You can replace `node-sass` (which is written in C) with the 100% compatible `sass` which is written in pure javascript.  Edit your package.json file and replace the sass version with: `"node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.30.0"`. This tricks npm to load sass for node-sass. I don't know why create-react-app chose the C node-sass over the pure javascript sass

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with node-gyp and macOs. Checkout: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-macos regarding xcode and command line.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu not macOs

Answer (score 0):

node-sass-chokidar doesn't look like it supports Node 16. You'll need node-sass 6+ for Node 16 support